# Retrieving the contents of PE file sections

Tags: c, pe, assembly, section

I am trying to get the contents of the .text section of a file (notepad.exe) using the following code:

```
#define SECHDROFFSET(a) ((LPVOID) ( (LPBYTE) a           + \
                    ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)a)->e_lfanew + \
                    sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)))

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER     pDosH;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS     pNtH;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSecH;

HANDLE hFile;

DWORD  dwFileSize, dwSectionSize, dwStubSize,
       dwVSize, dwOldProt, dwSpot, dwGap, bytes;

LPBYTE FileBuffer, SectionBuffer;
CHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];

printf("Input file path: ");
scanf("%s", &FileName);

// open it and get the size
hFile = CreateFileA(FileName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, 0);

// load it into memory
FileBuffer = (LPBYTE) malloc(dwFileSize);
ReadFile(hFile, FileBuffer, dwFileSize, &bytes, 0);

pDosH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) FileBuffer;

// basic checks
if(pDosH->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    return -1;

pNtH = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) (FileBuffer + pDosH->e_lfanew);

if(pNtH->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    return -2;

pSecH = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) SECHDROFFSET(FileBuffer);

while(memcmp(pSecH->Name, ".text", 5)) 
    pSecH++;
```

The problem is that the section names are not valid; when debugging I never see a string of type `.<section_name>` to take the value of `pSecH->Name`. They are always unprintable characters.

Am I reading from the correct offset?

Comment: `SECHDROFFSET()` is not a standard macro; I just Googled for it and the implementations I saw will often produce the wrong offset for the section table. Don't use `SECHDROFFSET()` since its formula is incorrect.

Comment: @Jason Geffner I've added the macro. How can I jump over the DOS header?

Comment: If you want to use a macro to find the section table, use `IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION()`, whose formula is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by using pSecH = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pNtH);

Comment: Glad it's working! I'll add that as an answer below now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the comments above, the `SECHDROFFSET()` macro formula is not reliable. You should instead use the macro `IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION()`.